# $\lim_{x\to-\infty} F(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} F(x) = 1$.

Tags: probability

$\lim_{x\to-\infty} F(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} F(x) = 1$.

What is the probabilistic meanings of these facts?

My guess was the first one mean $P(X=x) = 0$ and for the second the total probability is $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great basic probability question! We, first, assume $F(x)$ is the cumulative distribution function (cdf). If this is the case, we can say $\lim_{x \to -\infty} F(x) = \lim_{x \to -\infty} \text{P}(X \leq x) = 0$ to represent the observation that the *cumulative* distribution (e.g. the area under the pdf's curve) will tend to $0$ with lesser values in the distribution's support set (e.g. the values over which the distribution's variable is defined).

On the other hand, we say $\lim_{x \to \infty} F(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \text{P}(X \leq x) = 1$ to represent the observation that the cdf will tend towards $1$ with greater values in the distribution's support set. This should make sense intuitively, since the total probability cannot be greater than 1.

A simple example could involve the Normal distribution: consider its stereotypical bell-shaped curve. The farther to the left on the curve you look, the less cumulative area under the curve you'll see. Infinitely far to the left, the area under the curve will be so small that it is equivalent to $0$. The farther to the right on the curve you look, the more cumulative area you'll see. If you go infinitely far to the right, you'll accumulate a total area of $1$.

Answer (score 0):

They mean that $\lim_{x\to -\infty} P(X\le x)=0$ and that $\lim_{x\to \infty} P(X\le x)=1$. Since we are talking about $\sigma$-additive measures on $\sigma$-algebras, this implies $P(X\in\Bbb R)=P\left(X\in\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N} (-\infty, n]\right)=1$ and, by finiteness of the measure, that $P(X\in\emptyset)=P\left(X\in\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}(-\infty,-n]\right)=0$ (the latter is more of a necessity than actual additional information, though).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you think the last half  would need  to be states or is the first part sufficient?